# What is the diffrence in MouseEvent.CLICK & MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN on ActionScript 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'd like to know what is the difference between `MouseEvent.CLICK & MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`. 
Because when i use `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` for a button to set `full-screen` view its doesn't work, instead of this `MouseEvent.CLICK` works. So what was the reason.

Answer (score 7):

I don't specifically know about ActionScript, but in general a `mouse click` event consists of a `mouse down` event, *followed by* a `mouse up`.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. `CLICK` is down then up; `MOUSE_DOWN` is just down (like the start of a drag operation).

Comment: @zeh: it might be a little misleading to say anything about a drag operation. All you can really say is that `MOUSE_DOWN` is fired when the mouse button is pressed down, before it is released.

Comment: It's just an example of the typical use of `MOUSE_DOWN` when it's not about a click.

Comment: @zeh can CLICK be interpreted as "Drag" without "Move"?

Comment: It depends on how you interpret it. The mouse event system has no concept of a "drag". It interprets DOWN followed by UP as CLICK. So if the user does a drag without moving, yes, it'll be a CLICK. Hence why most mouse event handlers normally have a minimum moving threshold before they implement something as a "drag".

Answer (score 3):

MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN is dispatched when a user presses the mouse down but a MouseEvent.CLICK occurs when MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN is dispatched followed by a MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP event.

This is an important concept to consider when listening to events, in general I mostly use MouseEvent.CLICK on buttons as it is the logical interaction I would like to listen for. I want to make sure that button was both pressed and released.

And to answer why you cannot initilize full-screen mode:

> "The ActionScript that initiates
>   full-screen mode can be called only in
>   response to a mouse click or keypress.
>   If it is called in other situations,
>   it will be ignored (in ActionScript
>   2.0) or throw an exception (in ActionScript 3.0)."

For more information you can read this:
[Exploring full-screen mode in Flash Player 9](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html)

Answer (score 1):

In ActionScript 3.0 the difference between `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` an `MouseEvent.CLICK` is as Matt Ball says, that the `CLICK` event is the act of down the mouse button into an object, and release it in the SAME object.

If you down the button in an object and then release it in other object you will have the next events triggered (in order):

*Object 1*

```
MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT // and MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT
```

*Object 2*

```
MouseEvent.ROLL_IN // and MouseEvent.MOUSE_IN
MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP
```

But, if you press the button and release it in the same object you will have the next events triggered (in order):

*Object 1 (the only one)*

```
MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP
MouseEvent.CLICK
```